# How do I get tokens still unsupported after crowdsale?

Tags: tokens, exchanges

If I want a token, say GNT, that is not listed on exchanges and I missed the presale, what are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get GNTs from https://cryptoderivatives.market, a decentralised trustless exchange contract market. Send a small amount first to a contract address to test and check you receive the correct amount of tokens in your sending address. And don't send from an exchange wallet, but from a wallet you control, e.g., using Ethereum Wallet, https://www.myetherwallet.com or Parity. Users don't pay any fees except for the standard Ethereum transaction gas fees.

This site will soon allow for the listing of purchase and/or sale contracts on ERC20 compliant tokens.

Disclosure: I run this website.

Also, there is a [108 ETH Bug Bounty](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TokenTrader/wiki/TokenTraderFactory-And-TokenSellerFactory-Bug-Bounty) on the new upcoming smart contracts.

Other sources of information for unlisted tokens - https://www.reddit.com/r/ethtrader/ and slack forums for the project, e.g. http://golemproject.org:3000 .

Comment: Thanks! How exactly do you see GNT on the Ethereum Wallet? Is it supported?

Comment: Yup, it is supported. See https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TokenTrader/wiki/GNT-%E2%80%90-Golem-Network-Token for instructions.

Answer (score 2):

**GNT**

See [Golem Network Token on coinmarketcap.com](https://coinmarketcap.com/assets/golem-network-tokens/#markets) (CMC). CMC lists the markets GNT is trading on and the volume. Currently, Liqui has the highest volume and might be your best bet. GNT also trades on [mkr.market](https://mkr.market/#trade/W-ETH/W-GNT), which is a decentralized exchange (not tracked by CMC). It should also be noted that Julian Zawistowski of the Golem Project [just submitted a request to Poloniex](https://twitter.com/golemproject/status/824188261551788039) to have GNT listed, so it should trade there soon.

**Other Tokens**

Consider using [CMC](https://coinmarketcap.com/) to research any other token. If it's not found on CMC, try to discover the token project's subreddit - it will typically list any exchanges on the side bar. If there are no apparent exchanges, the community may simply trade the token in the sub by posting seller/buyer threads and using trusted community members for escrow.